# Can I assign a different DNS for 192.168.*.*?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, mac-osx, subnet, pptp

I'm trying to connect to my company's network via PPTP VPN from Mac OS X.

I had [a problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/274882/cant-resolve-host-through-vpn-connection-from-mac-os-x) which turned out to be wrong netmask configuration which prevented `192.168.10.16` and `17` DNS servers from being accessible. The gateway IP is `192.168.7.117` and the mask for some reason was set to `255.255.255.0`.

I worked around it (perhaps, in a wrong way) by routing everything with the `255.255.0.0` netmask to the gateway:

```
sudo route add -net 192.168.7.218 192.168.7.117 255.255.0.0
```

Now, both my working computer (`192.168.11.56`) and DNS (`192.168.10.16`) are pingable.
**However I can't come up with a way to assign this DNS for this particular subnet.**

Merely setting company DNS in VPN interface settings and normal DNS in my Bluetooth doesn't do the trick. How can I do this in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to fix this is to configure the VPN server to allocate the correct DNS server names along with the domain suffixes that should be used with these servers (if it is a split-tunnel vpn).

A workaround, if you are unable to fix this is create a file on you Mac:

```
/etc/resolver/yourdomain.com
```

The contents should be something like:

```
nameserver 192.168.10.§6
domain yourdomain.com
port 53
```

This should cause the resolver to use the specified server for lookups in the domain specified.

Comment: I still can't access the server I need, but at least DNS started working properly. Thanks!